# JNA: what is the purpose of getFieldOrder() in structure class

Tags: java, class, visual-c++, structure, jna

I am trying to call C++ function present within a dll file,C++ function takes structure object as parameter by reference,and function will assign values in that function,

So in my java application in order to pass structure object to a function i did write like this:

```
interface SomeInterface extends Library {
    SomeInterface instance = (SomeInterface) Native.loadLibrary("mydll", SomeInterface.class);
    int someFunction(StructClass.ByReference strobject);

    public static class StructClass extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends tTIDFUDeviceInfo implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public short xxx = 0;
        public char yyy = '0';
        public boolean zzz = false
        public String www = new String();

        protected ArrayList getFieldOrder() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList fields = new ArrayList();
            fields.add(Arrays.asList(new short{xxx}));
            fields.add(Arrays.asList(new char{yyy}));
            fields.add(Arrays.asList(new boolean{zzz}));
            fields.add(Arrays.asList(new String{www}));
            return fields;
        }
    }
}
```

my main class

```
public class Someclass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SomeInterface.StructClass.ByReference sss=new SomeInterface.StructClass.ByReference();
        SomeInterface obj = SomeInterface.instance;
        obj.someFunction(sss);
    }
}
```

when i tried this it is giving me

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

so what do i do?is there any problem in getFieldOrder() function?

can anyone explain me how exactly JNA will convert the class object in java to structure object in C++?

actually exception is happening at calling the function but i don't get it why it happening so.

Answer (score 1):

[From the JavaDoc:](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/3.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#getFieldOrder%28%29)

> Return this Structure's field names in their proper order

However, you are going to quickly run up against the fact that you're attempting to map a JNA `Structure` onto a C++ class, which simply won't work.  JNA does not provide any automatic translation between JNA and C++ classes.

**EDIT**

To be explicit:

```
protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "www" });
}
```

Comment: that's the only way i know how structure of C++ is represented in java using JNA and send that structure object as function parameter,so what is the solution to that exception ?the only arraylist i am using in my code is in **getfieldoreder()** function so thought that function implementation is the problem and asked for clarification

Comment: I tried it but it is giving me compile time error saying Type mismatch:cannot convert from short to String...as my xxx variable is of type short but we are assigning it to string array.so i separately assigned each variable as shown in the code in post. so it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `code`  public class JVisaCallback extends Structure {
    public int handler;
    
    public JVisaCallback() {
        handler = 1;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * This method returns the field order of this Structure class.
     * @return field order
     */
    @Override
    protected ArrayList getFieldOrder() {
        ArrayList fields = new ArrayList();
        fields.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"handler"}));
        return fields;
    }
}

Comment: Sorry for my previous messed up edit. Here is a slightly better version:   Instantiating the class below throws the same exception @MAHANTESH mentioned. What am I missing?  `public class JVisaCallback extends Structure {public int handler;
    
    /**
     * This method returns the field order of this Structure class.
     * @return field order
     */
    @Override
    protected ArrayList getFieldOrder() {
        ArrayList fields = new ArrayList();
        fields.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"handler"}));
        return fields;
    }
}`

Comment: Compare your `getFieldOrder()` with the one in the answer.  They're not even close.