# Java detect inactivity on Windows

Tags: java, winapi, jna

Ive found the following code to detect inactivity;

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Utility method to retrieve the idle time on Windows and sample code to test it.
 * JNA shall be present in your classpath for this to work (and compile).
 * @author ochafik
 */
public class Win32IdleTime {

    public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);

        /**
         * Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.
         * @see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx
         * @return number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.
         */
        public int GetTickCount();
    };

    public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        /**
         * Contains the time of the last input.
         * @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/userinput/keyboardinput/keyboardinputreference/keyboardinputstructures/lastinputinfo.asp
         */
        public static class LASTINPUTINFO extends Structure {
            public int cbSize = 8;

            /// Tick count of when the last input event was received.
            public int dwTime;

            @
            Override
            protected List getFieldOrder() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves the time of the last input event.
         * @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/userinput/keyboardinput/keyboardinputreference/keyboardinputfunctions/getlastinputinfo.asp
         * @return time of the last input event, in milliseconds
         */
        public boolean GetLastInputInfo(LASTINPUTINFO result);
    };

    /**
     * Get the amount of milliseconds that have elapsed since the last input event
     * (mouse or keyboard)
     * @return idle time in milliseconds
     */
    public static int getIdleTimeMillisWin32() {
        User32.LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new User32.LASTINPUTINFO();
        User32.INSTANCE.GetLastInputInfo(lastInputInfo);
        return Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime;
    }

    enum State {
        UNKNOWN, ONLINE, IDLE, AWAY
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Only implemented on Windows");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        State state = State.UNKNOWN;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        for (;;) {
            int idleSec = getIdleTimeMillisWin32() / 1000;

            State newState =
                idleSec < 30 ? State.ONLINE :
                idleSec > 5 * 60 ? State.AWAY : State.IDLE;

            if (newState != state) {
                state = newState;
                System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()) + " # " + state);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason i am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
```

Any ideas what could be done to solve this?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace and point us to that line throwing exception. Also add `e.printsStackTrace()` into your `catch` block.

Comment: This is causing the error `public boolean GetLastInputInfo(LASTINPUTINFO result);`

Comment: Because your code throws that exact error right in the middle.

Comment: To avoid `UnsupportedOperationException` the operation should be supported, which means implementing `protected List getFieldOrder()`

Comment: @Stewart i dont quite follow, what do you mean?

Comment: Your own code is throwing that error.  You need to provide an implementation of `getFieldOrder()`

Comment: @Alosyius The only way to make it clearer is if you were to put line numbers in your code sample, then we could tell you the line number that is throwing the exception. But you know, I think stack traces do that already by default ...

Comment: The code is found in several places on the internet; it is, however, outdated. The LASTINPUTINFO class needs to implement a getFieldOrder() method as pointed out before; an easy to understand example can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jna-users/structure/jna-users/7B8tR44Vi1Q/exZNdxui0X4J

Answer (score 3):

You have a class named `LASTINPUTINFO` which extends the abstract class [com.sun.jna.Structure](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html). As commented by Stewart and Jim Garrison, your implementation of the [getFieldOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510975/jnawhat-is-the-purpose-of-getfieldorder-in-structure-class) method is throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` exception. This method implementation was probably auto generated by your IDE.
When this method is called for getting the Structure's field names in their proper order the exception is thrown.

```
/**
* Contains the time of the last input.
* @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/userinput/keyboardinput/keyboardinputreference/keyboardinputstructures/lastinputinfo.asp
*/
public static class LASTINPUTINFO extends Structure {
    public int cbSize = 8;

    /// Tick count of when the last input event was received.
    public int dwTime;

    @
    Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

You can solve this problem by properly implementing the `getFieldOrder` method.